# typo3 extetension: issue with object: fe_user

Tags: typo3

I am reading a extension file, and see below codes:

```
if ($job && $job['cruser_id'] != $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid'])
```

I find out `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user` is the object of class:`tslib_feuserauth`, i checked the file: `class.tslib_feuserauth.php`,

my question is :

what is `user['uid']`? `user` is an array, but in `class.tslib_feuserauth.php` did not see such codes like: `$this->user['uid']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user is `logged`  this array represents user's row from DB and just contains all columns of `fe_users` table otherwise it's `FALSE`, so you can use it to determine the login state:

```
if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user){
    $msg = 'You are logged as ' . $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['username'];
} else {
    $msg = 'You need to login first';
}
```